# segmentation fault by overloading operators with ifstream returning

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I wrote this program in c++ in ubuntu. I wrote 2 operator overloadings like bellow. But I received "segmentation fault(core dumped)". What should I do?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class Complex{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    Complex(double a,double b){
         x=a;
         y=b;
    }

    void setx(double a){
         x=a;
    }

    void sety(double b){
         y=b;
    }

    double getx(){
         return x;
    }

    double gety(){
         return y;
    }
};
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& file1,Complex &c){
     double d,e;
     file1>>d>>e;
     c.setx(d);
     c.sety(e);
     return file1;
}

ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& file1,char &ch){
     file1>>ch;
     return file1;
}
int  main(){
Complex c1(1,2);
Complex c2(1,2);
char ch;
ifstream file("input.data",ios::in);
file>>c1>>ch>>c2; 
return 0;
}
```

In the input.data I have something like bellow:

```
1 4 + 2 3
3 1 - 4 8
```

The purpose of the program is to getting complex numbers from a file with the operator between them.

Comment: use [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: That's right. But I want to write the program in this form. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program gets into an infinite recursion when you do this:

```
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& file1,char &ch){
    file1>>ch;
    return file1;
}
```

The first line calls the same `operator>>` for the `char`, so you end up with stack overflowing.

Since `operator>>` is defined for `std::istream`, and because `std::ifstream` can be passed to operators on `std::istream`, simply removing your implementation will fix this problem ([demo](http://ideone.com/FJl2Yr)).